# Replace given line in files in Python

Tags: python

I have several files, and I need to replace third line in them:

```
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
new_3rd_line = 'new third line'
```

What is the best way to do this?

Files are big enough, several 100mb's files.

Comment: What would you like it to do when there's an empty file, or a file with only one line?

Comment: best in terms of what? Speed/Scalability (what about doing this 100,000 times) Flexibility (what about replacing the 10,000th line)?  Memory? (what about performing this on 4GB log files)?  Need moar info.

Comment: I tired `for line in file` with counter, saving every line `if counter == 3`, but I want to see more or less optimal way for this.

Comment: Someone should also mention this is like a 60 character shell script...

Comment: @Triptych: Maybe you should. :-P

Comment: cat file1.txt | awk '{if (NR != 3) print NR " " $0}' | head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this solution: [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close

def replace_3_line(file):
    new_3rd_line = 'new_3_line\n'
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    new_file = open(abs_path,'w')
    old_file = open(file)
    counter = 0
    for line in old_file:
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter == 3:
            new_file.write(new_3rd_line)
        else:
            new_file.write(line)
    #close temp file
    new_file.close()
    close(fh)
    old_file.close()
    #Remove original file
    remove(file)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, file)

replace_3_line('tmp.ann')
```

But it does not work with files that contains non English charecters.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxx\replace.py", line 27, in <module>
    replace_3_line('tmp.ann')
  File "D:\xxx\replace.py", line 12, in replace_3_line
    for line in old_file:
  File "C:\Python31\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 32: character maps to <undefined>
```

That is bad. Where's python unicode? (file is utf8, python3).

File is:

```
фвыафыв
sdadf
试试
阿斯达а
阿斯顿飞
```

Comment: ok, it is bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109022/unicodedecodeerror-while-using-cyryllic. Quite frustrating.

Comment: you should use `open()` with `encoding='utf8'`. Feels good now :)