# UnicodeDecodeError in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, pycharm, cp1251

Its a reference to [UnicodeDecodeError while using cyryllic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109022/unicodedecodeerror-while-using-cyryllic) .
 I have same problem with Python 3.3 and Pycharm 2.7.2
Tryed to hardcode encoding in code, manually specifying encoding in Pycharm options, but no effect. It still tries to open utf-8 file with cp1251 lib.

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 129.314)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1481, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1124, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_execfile.py", line 33, in execfile
contents = stream.read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 2839: character maps to <undefined>
```

In debug tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3669 this problem marked as solved, but its still here.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

The sample code from that ticket worked fine for me with Python 3.3 and PyCharm 2.7.3 (2 lines:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 print("януари")
```

).

Does it work for you?

Do you use remote debugger?

There is another one open bug that could be related: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10241

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work. But Pycharm correctly says that utf-8 hardcoded in file.

This bug report looks similar, thank you.

Comment: Note to others: This did work for me. Although the interpreter is python 3.x, it seems that pycharm still wants to see the unicode declaration.

Comment: The bus still exists in mid 2018. Amazing... Don't buy PyCharm!